# Android xamarin c# how to get TwoLineListItem in listview

Tags: c#, android, asp.net, xamarin

I have a question about my xamarin android project
currently i ran into an issue with my listview i have 1 row 
and want to add some text under it for example an description

Currently

[image: Currently]
The Idea

[image: The Idea]
the code im currently using is:

```
    ListView listView;

    protected override void OnCreate(Bundle bundle)
    {
        base.OnCreate(bundle);

        SetContentView(Resource.Layout.Main);
         Bla WebS = new Bla ();

        var ListSort = WebS.Fetch(Core.AdresID, DateTime.Today.Year, null);
        var Sorts = ListSort.Where(i => i.Date >= DateTime.Today).Select(k=> k.Sort).ToArray();

        var Dates = ListSort.Where(i => i.Date >= DateTime.Today).Select(k => k.Date).ToArray();

        listView = FindViewById<ListView>(Resource.Id.ListView1);
        listView.Adapter = new ArrayAdapter(this, Android.Resource.Layout.SimpleListItemSingleChoice, Sorts);
        listView.ChoiceMode = ChoiceMode.Single;
        listView.ItemClick += new EventHandler<AdapterView.ItemClickEventArgs>(listView_ItemClick);

    }

    void listView_ItemClick(object sender, AdapterView.ItemClickEventArgs e)
    {
        ListView listView = sender as ListView;
        if (listView != null)
        {
            MessageBox("Chosen item: " + listView.Adapter.GetItem(e.Position));
        }

    }
```

Does someone know how to reach that ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should subclass `ArrayAdapter` (or I use mainly `BaseAdapter`), and then you can setup a custom layout for each row.

Here is an example on Xamarin's [doc website](http://docs.xamarin.com/guides/android/user_interface/working_with_listviews_and_adapters/part_3_-_customizing_a_listview%27s_appearance/), go to the custom row layout part.